# VSCode Find and Replace with varying pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I have a bunch of instances in a codebase that has this patterns

`translate(k.SOME_KEY)`

`translate(k.ANOTHER_KEY)`

and I want to find and replace this pattern to:

`translate('SOME_KEY')`

`translate('ANOTHER_KEY')`

Is this possible using regex and the VSCode find and replace?

Comment: Sure you can, but it's not really a good idea. Try [this feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek) instead.

Comment: Well, my comment did not answer your question because it is not an answer. Rename code using regex has always been a big no-no, so I thought you would take the safe path and check all references before replace them; obviously I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by activating the regex search and setting `translate\(k\.(.+)\)` as the search and `translate('$1')` as the replace.

By using the (.+) it will group everything matched until finding the `)` which is placed after, and it will store it in $1 (which is basically the matcher)

[image]

Comment: my man. will try this asap and get back to you.

Comment: what if there is more on the line? use `(.+?)` or maybe more failsafe `([^)]+)`